# Android "set as" intent

Tags: android

The music player app on my Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini (Android 4.1.2) have a "Set as" action you can perform on a music track, and it will offer you to choose "Phone ringtone", "Caller ringtone" and "Alarm tone".

I assume that this will launch some intent with the music track.

Which intent action is used to do this? How can I do the same from my own Android app?

Is this Samsung specific, or Android generic? I suspect it is Android generic since there exists an icon resource android.R.drawable.ic_menu_set_as in the Android SDK.